# brightness of the screen

Tags: startup, brightness

Every time after I restart I have to enter this in the terminal to set the brightness:

```
xrandr -q | grep " connected"
xrandr --output LVDS --brightness 0.5
```

Could someone tell me if there is there any way to set up the brightness and remain like that even after a restart?

Answer (score 6):

You can take that code, turn it into a script , and add that script to startup applications, so that on every login this runs automatically.

Script would be like so:

```
#!/bin/bash


xrandr --output LVDS --brightness 0.5
```

Save it in a file, e.g. myscript.sh. , preferably in `/usr/bin`, but not necessarily. Give that script executable permissions with `chmod +x scriptname.sh`

Then add full path to script in Startup Applications or make your own `.desktop` file in `/home/yourusername/.config/autostart`

Comment: Why do you need the `xrandr -q | grep " connected"` in the script?

Comment: @A.B. I simply copied OP's two lines over when I was speed-writing the answer >_<

Comment: Thank you very much Serg, I will do it, but tell me please shouldn't be normal to can adjust the brightness from the keyboard shortcuts(windows+f7 in my case, like in Wondows OS) or from other settings from the Xubuntu system, without do add any script to the startup? Thanks.

Comment: @XPDIN yes, you should be able to use function keys. For instance on my machine it's fn + f6 and fn + f7, but sometimes there's issues, probably related to drivers. You can post another question here, and guys can take a look

Answer (score 0):

clone the script on my https://github.com/el-beth/backlight.sh.git and paste the `backlight.sh` script file in any of the directories in $PATH of your shell for instance /bin or /usr/bin and make `backlight.sh` executable. After doing this, just create a .desktop file in `/home/USERNAME/.config/autostart`.